# How to connect to postgres from within a docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, psql

I'm new to docker and postgres. It should be mentioned that my problem only occurs with docker-compose.Here's my .yml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:**
```

When I run `docker-compose run postgres bash` and then run `psql -U postgres` i get the following error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Try a TCP connection: `psql -U postgres -h localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `docker-compose run postgres bash` you are replacing the entry-point script of the image with bash. So the DB is not running. Try

```
$ docker-compose up --detach postgres
$ docker-compose exec postgres bash
```

instead.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as correct then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `psql -U postgres -h postgres`

specifying the host with the network you've created.